# Want player's FB profile pic (DP) getting player's FB gaming pic Unity

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-graph-api, fbx

I'm working on a game with Unity and FB in this game I wanted to show user FB profile pic.

I am doing this

```
FB.API("/me/picture?redirect=false", HttpMethod.GET, GetFBPic);

private void GetFBPic(IGraphResult result)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Error) && !result.Cancelled)
        {
            IDictionary data = result.ResultDictionary["data"] as IDictionary;
            string url = data["url"] as string;
        }
    }
```

for getting FB profile pic but the url here gives the FB gaming pic not FB profile pic i.e FB DP
how can I get FB profile pic (DP) url.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veKiS.png)

I'm searching this from long time but not getting anything, Anyone please help me in this

Answer (score 2):

> but the url here gives the FB gaming pic not FB profile pic i.e FB DP how can I get FB profile pic (DP) url.

It is up to the user, whether they want to enter your app using their standard Facebook user profile, or a special gaming profile.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/acquire/login-for-gaming#requesting-user-s-profile-picture:

> If user chooses the Facebook Profile option, both gaming_profile and gaming_user_picture permissions will be granted to application.
> `GET graph.fb.gg/v7.0/me/picture` // return profile picture
>
> If user chooses the gaming name and avatar option, only gaming_profile permission will be granted to application.
> `GET graph.fb.gg/v7.0/me/picture` // return avatar

Comment: Thanks it works but while log in user need to select form gaming profile and from Facebook Profile is there any way to remove gaming profile option only Facebook Profile option can be shown or just request for name and profile pic like this game Pirate King https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jellybtn.cashkingmobile&hl=en_IN&gl=US

Comment: No. Users have the explicit choice, whether they want to use your app using their Facebook profile, or just a "player profile" with just name & avatar.